# min Function returning multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, min

I'm using the following query, but it still returns the rows grouped by period. If I eliminate any of the group by fields, it will say not a group by function.
I've been digging around in analytic functions, but it still returns multiple rows, if it works at all.
Thanks!

```
select 
       AB1.ID,
       AB1.NAME,
       AB1.ACCOUNT_BALANCE,
       AB1.DELINQUENCY,
       AB1.DELINQUENCY_DESC,
       min(AB1.PERIOD) as oldest_per_owed,
       AB1.bal_sum

from
(select RA.ID,
       RA.NAME,
       RA.ACCOUNT_BALANCE,
       RA.DELINQUENCY,
       RA.DELINQUENCY_DESC,
       RAD.PERIOD,
        sum(RAD.BALANCE) as bal_sum
  from RAD RAD
       RA RA
 where ( RA.ID = RAD.ID )
   and ( RA.DELINQUENCY in('02','03','05'))
   and (RA.BALANCE >0
        or
        RAD.BALANCE <0)
group by
RECEIVABLE_ACCOUNT.ID,
       RA.NAME,
       RA.ACCOUNT_BALANCE,
       RA.DELINQUENCY,
       RA.DELINQUENCY_DESC,
       RAD.PERIOD
order by RA.NAME)  AB1

group by
       AB1.ID,
       AB1.NAME,
       AB1.ACCOUNT_BALANCE,
       AB1.DELINQUENCY,
       AB1.DELINQUENCY_DESC,
       --AB1.PERIOD,
       AB1.bal_sum      
Order by 2,6 asc
```

Here are my results:

```
|ID |NAME   |ACCOUNT_BALANCE |DELINQUENCY   |DELINQUENCY_DESC   |OLDEST_TERM    |BAL_SUM
---     ---     ---              ---            ---                     ---             ---
|111    |Tom    |500             |AA            |D1                 |201010     |500
|222    |Dick   |501             |AA            |D1                 |201110     |250
|222    |Dick   |501             |AA            |D1                 |201190     |251
|333    |Harry  |600             |BB            |D2                 |201690     |600
|444    |Jane   |601             |AA            |D1                 |200510     |101
|444    |Jane   |601             |AA            |D1                 |200690     |500
|555    |Sally  |700             |AA            |D1                 |200890     |340
|555    |Sally  |700             |AA            |D1                 |200910     |360
```

Comment: Thanks Lyndey.  It would be great to see a bit of data to reproduce the problem.  Any chance you can include a few rows of `RA` and `RAD` that will demonstrate the problem?  Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Lyndey for the updated data.  I added an answer that tries to fit  the example data you provided but had to guess a bit at what `RA` and `RAD` should look like.  If misinterpreted how `RA` and `RAD` should look (or the goal here), maybe adding some more `RA` and `RAD` data would also help clarify.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your goal correctly, you'd like one row per delinquent account `id`, that includes the oldest period for the account, and you'd like to include the `bal_sum` from that period (only).

If this is the case, maybe `KEEP` would meet your needs.

I'm guessing at what the data looks like in `RA` and `RAD`, but here's an example:

Create and load the test tables (with multiple `RAD` records for some `RA` records, and one new user Benedetto that is not delinquent and not expected to appear in the result):

```
CREATE TABLE RAD (
  ID      NUMBER,
  "PERIOD" NUMBER,
  BALANCE NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO RAD VALUES (111, 201010, 500);
INSERT INTO RAD VALUES (222, 201010, 120);
INSERT INTO RAD VALUES (222, 201010, 130);
INSERT INTO RAD VALUES (222, 201190, 101);
INSERT INTO RAD VALUES (222, 201190, 150);
INSERT INTO RAD VALUES (333, 201690, 600);
INSERT INTO RAD VALUES (444, 200510, 101);
INSERT INTO RAD VALUES (444, 200690, 500);
INSERT INTO RAD VALUES (555, 200890, 340);
INSERT INTO RAD VALUES (555, 200910, 360);
INSERT INTO RAD VALUES (666, 200911, 200);


CREATE TABLE RA (
  ID               NUMBER,
  NAME             VARCHAR2(256),
  ACCOUNT_BALANCE  NUMBER,
  DELINQUENCY      VARCHAR2(3),
  DELINQUENCY_DESC VARCHAR2(256),
  BALANCE          NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO RA VALUES (111, 'Tom',500,'02','D2',1);
INSERT INTO RA VALUES (222, 'Dick',501,'03','D3',1);
INSERT INTO RA VALUES (333, 'Harry',600,'05','D5',1);
INSERT INTO RA VALUES (444, 'Jane',600,'02','D2',1);
INSERT INTO RA VALUES (555, 'Sally',600,'03','D3',1);
INSERT INTO RA VALUES (666, 'Benedetto',23,'03','D3',-20);
```

Running the original query (with `RECEIVABLE_ACCOUNT.ID` changed to `RA.ID`, etc.) gives something resembling the eight rows in your example:

```
SELECT
  AB1.ID,
  AB1.NAME,
  AB1.ACCOUNT_BALANCE,
  AB1.DELINQUENCY,
  AB1.DELINQUENCY_DESC,
  min(AB1.PERIOD) AS OLDEST_PER_OWED,
  AB1.BAL_SUM
FROM
  (SELECT
     RA.ID,
     RA.NAME,
     RA.ACCOUNT_BALANCE,
     RA.DELINQUENCY,
     RA.DELINQUENCY_DESC,
     RAD.PERIOD,
     sum(RAD.BALANCE) AS BAL_SUM
   FROM RAD RAD,
     RA RA
   WHERE (RA.ID = RAD.ID)
         AND (RA.DELINQUENCY IN ('02', '03', '05'))
         AND (RA.BALANCE > 0
              OR
              RAD.BALANCE < 0)
   GROUP BY
     RA.ID,
     RA.NAME,
     RA.ACCOUNT_BALANCE,
     RA.DELINQUENCY,
     RA.DELINQUENCY_DESC,
     RAD.PERIOD
   ORDER BY RA.NAME) AB1
GROUP BY
  AB1.ID,
  AB1.NAME,
  AB1.ACCOUNT_BALANCE,
  AB1.DELINQUENCY,
  AB1.DELINQUENCY_DESC,
  AB1.BAL_SUM
ORDER BY 1, 6 ASC;
```

result:

```
ID   NAME   ACCOUNT_BALANCE  DELINQUENCY  DELINQUENCY_DESC  OLDEST_PER_OWED  BAL_SUM  
111  Tom    500              02           D2                201010           500      
222  Dick   501              03           D3                201010           250      
222  Dick   501              03           D3                201190           251      
333  Harry  600              05           D5                201690           600      
444  Jane   600              02           D2                200510           101      
444  Jane   600              02           D2                200690           500      
555  Sally  600              03           D3                200890           340      
555  Sally  600              03           D3                200910           360
```

To get only the oldest `period`, and the `bal_sum` for it, we can apply `KEEP`.  This will grab the oldest `period` and pull in the corresponding `bal_sum`(s) for it, and if there is tie (multiple `bal_sum` for the oldest `period`, it will resolve the tie by `MIN`.  From the look of this data, I wouldn't expect any aggregation resolution to be necessary)

If we change the query to `KEEP` instead, we now get only one row per `ID`.  This row has the oldest `period`, and the `bal_sum` for that period.  For example, Jane's oldest period is 200510, with `bal_sum` of 101.

```
SELECT
  AB1.ID,
  AB1.NAME,
  AB1.ACCOUNT_BALANCE,
  AB1.DELINQUENCY,
  AB1.DELINQUENCY_DESC,
  min(AB1.PERIOD) AS OLDEST_PER_OWED,
  MIN(AB1.BAL_SUM) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY AB1.PERIOD ASC) AS OLDEST_PER_BAL_SUM
FROM
  (SELECT
     RA.ID,
     RA.NAME,
     RA.ACCOUNT_BALANCE,
     RA.DELINQUENCY,
     RA.DELINQUENCY_DESC,
     RAD.PERIOD,
     sum(RAD.BALANCE) AS BAL_SUM
   FROM RAD RAD,
     RA RA
   WHERE (RA.ID = RAD.ID)
         AND (RA.DELINQUENCY IN ('02', '03', '05'))
         AND (RA.BALANCE > 0
              OR
              RAD.BALANCE < 0)
   GROUP BY
     RA.ID,
     RA.NAME,
     RA.ACCOUNT_BALANCE,
     RA.DELINQUENCY,
     RA.DELINQUENCY_DESC,
     RAD.PERIOD
   ORDER BY RA.NAME) AB1
GROUP BY
  AB1.ID,
  AB1.NAME,
  AB1.ACCOUNT_BALANCE,
  AB1.DELINQUENCY,
  AB1.DELINQUENCY_DESC
ORDER BY 1, 6 ASC;
```

Result:

```
ID   NAME   ACCOUNT_BALANCE  DELINQUENCY  DELINQUENCY_DESC  OLDEST_PER_OWED  OLDEST_PER_BAL_SUM  
111  Tom    500              02           D2                201010           500                 
222  Dick   501              03           D3                201010           250                 
333  Harry  600              05           D5                201690           600                 
444  Jane   600              02           D2                200510           101                 
555  Sally  600              03           D3                200890           340
```

Comment: Thanks @Lyndey good to hear.  If any clarification I can provide just let me know.  Also, if this post (or another) has answered your question, please consider accepting an answer; it helps to categorize the questions.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are grouping by bal_sum, which was grouped by Period in your subquery.  Change your Select statement to:

```
select 
       AB1.ID,
       AB1.NAME,
       AB1.ACCOUNT_BALANCE,
       AB1.DELINQUENCY,
       AB1.DELINQUENCY_DESC,
       min(AB1.PERIOD) as oldest_per_owed,
       sum(AB1.bal_sum) as bal_sum
```

And remove bal_sum from the Group By at the end

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me the total account balance, not the oldest balance.